# Class method not being called in Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, methods

Here is where I call the class method. The call is made after a NSURLRequest is finished. All values are there, nothing is nil

```
[MemberInfo SetMemberInfo:memberId groupId:groupId token:token withContext:_context];
```

Here is the method implemented in the class generated by the core data "MemberInfo+CoreDataProperties.m"

```
+ (bool)SetMemberInfo:(NSString *)memberId groupId:(NSString *)groupId token:(NSString *)token withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSManagedObject *memberInfoObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MemberInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [memberInfoObject setValue:memberId forKey:@"memberId"];
    [memberInfoObject setValue:groupId forKey:@"groupId"];
    [memberInfoObject setValue:token forKey:@"token"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I have zero errors, and nothing in the logs that explains why. But this class method 'SetMemberInfo' is never hit. Any clues?

EDIT **
Full code where I call method

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error == nil)
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200)
        {
            id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

            if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && error == nil)
            {
                NSString *groupId = _tfGroupId.text;
                NSString *memberId = _tfMemberId.text;
                NSString *token = [object valueForKey:@"token"];

                [MemberInfo SetMemberInfo:memberId groupId:groupId token:token withContext:_context];
            }
        }
    }

}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

Comment: Post the code from where you call SetMemberInfo

Comment: What happens when you call that method ?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I added more code

Comment: @Rajesh Nothing happens. I have a breakpoint where I call the method and it does hit that line, but then moves on. Never calling the method

Comment: Could it be a context issue?

Comment: Do you get into the if branch where you're calling this method?

Comment: @linuxer : Have u declared your method in MemberInfo.h ? In objective C only the methods declared in .h file interface section are visible outside I mean available to be accessed publicly. Make sure you have it .h files

Comment: Did you maybe have two categories that both implement `+[MemberInfo  SetMemberInfo:groupId:token:withContext:]`?

Comment: I only had it in one and I did have it in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

Must be something to do with the class that I has the class method in. I moved it to another class and it now makes the call.